# How to make new data type globally accessible in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, types, global, enumeration

Imagine we are making a game.  The difficulty of this game can be changed in real-time (mid-game) and will be controllable at all times with three buttons that are always on screen.

The Swift type that represents this app "state" is:

```
enum CurrentDifficultyState {
    case low
    case medium
    case max
}
```

Lets say we have put this code in the ViewController.

But... in our model... we have something like enemyController.swift that has a member function like `generateEnemy(currentDifficulty: CurrentDifficultyState)`.

The "difficulty" of this enemy will depend on the state of this enum at the moment it spawns.

When we do it like this, though, XCode complains (from inside the file enemyController.swift) that there is no such type as "CurrentDifficultyState" presumably because it hasn't been defined inside the enemyController.swift file (it was written in the ViewController file).

So... what is the proper way to handle this?  Where can we move this code to (or what keyword is it missing) so that it will be a global (static?) accepted type just like `String` or `Int`... accessible to all classes across the app?

What I ended up doing was creating a new swift file called "myGlobalTypes.swift" and putting the enum code in there.

This works!

But this seems like a trashy way to do it.

Could anyone enlighten me?  Thank you!

PS - Please don't ask for more code... the "game" thing was just a hypothetical example to give some context to the question (which is general)... but I'm not experienced enough to ask the real question point-blank because I don't know all the relevant terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your `enum` at the top level scope in whatever file you want. For instance, put it inside a enemyController.swift file at the top level (outside the `UIViewController` class)

Answer (score 2):

Putting the enum in a separate file is by no means "trashy" -- IMO, if it's an important type it's good to put it in a prominent place.

Your original question is hard to answer without more code. There's no problem with putting a type in a file and using it in another file as long as you don't mark it `private`/`fileprivate` and stay in the same module. I would guess that you put the enum inside another class, in which case you still could use it in other files if you would use the full type name, e.g. `OtherClass.currentDifficultyState`.

A final, unrelated tip: about 99.9% of all Swift code in the world starts type names with an uppercase letter, and I strongly advise you to follow this convention -- it makes working with other programmers and external libs much smoother.

Answer (score 2):

In ViewController file:

```
// file start
enum currentDifficultyState {
...
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
...
}
// file end
```